# Laravel Blade create comma separated list

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have this foreach:

```
@foreach ($ProdottoAccessori as $prodotto)
    @if($scheda->id == $prodotto->id)
        @foreach($prodotto['accessori'] as $acc)
           @foreach($acc['accessoriLang'] as $accNome)
                <span>{!! $accNome->accessori !!}</span>{{ $loop->last ? '' : ', ' }}
            @endforeach
        @endforeach
    @endif
@endforeach
```

that would put a comma after each item but not after the last. I think the code is correct but it doesn't work and I don't know why.

**EDIT**
This is the controller part for `$ProdottoAccessori`

```
$ProdottoAccessori = App\Product::has('accessori')->with([
    'productsLang',
      'accessori' => function ($query)  use ($array_prod_id){
          $query->with([
            'accessoriLang'
          ]);
       }
    ])->get();
```

Comment: You could achieve all this with Collection or simply by using implode function - let me write an example.

Comment: why dont you use `explode()`

Comment: @SebastianSulinski I suspected I was using too much code, but I'm new to Laravel. Every suggest is very welcome!!

Comment: Could you update your question with the actual structure of the `$ProdottoAccessori` - what indexes does it contain etc. From what I can see you have relationship to `accessori` and this one has relationship with `accessoriLang`, but please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: that's correct, going to update the question

Comment: I've updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok - so here's what I've come up with:

Outside of view - either within the controller or any class that would take care of it - then inject it to the view, you cold do the following:

```php
$products = $ProdottoAccessori->map(function($product) {
    $product->accessori = $product->accessori->map(function($accessori) {
        $accessori->accessoriLangString = '<span>'.$accessori->accessoriLang->pluck('accessori')->implode('</span>, <span>').'</span>';
        return $accessori;
    });
    return $product;
});
```

Now in the view you can do something like this:

```php
@foreach ($products as $prodotto)
    @if($scheda->id == $prodotto->id)
        @foreach($prodotto->accessori as $acc)
            {{ $acc->accessoriLangString }}
        @endforeach
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Alternatively you could also do it this way

```php
@foreach ($products as $prodotto)
    @if($scheda->id == $prodotto->id)
        {{ $prodotto->accessori->pluck('accessoriLangString')->implode('') }}
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: I need the list of all products with the relative accessory of each product. That's the reason why I'm passing `$array_prod_id` to the query builder for $ProdottoAccessori. In your answer you are insulating a single product that's not what I need

Comment: now it returns `Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.`

Comment: I had to do some trick to your code, but finally it works. I put the solution in an answer.

Comment: Sorry - I've forgotten about it - updated my answer.

Comment: I've put my own answer, but I'm not sure of those 2 implode

Comment: You could flatten it, but I wasn't sure if you need access to all those other properties of `accessori ` and `accessoriLang` - the way I've done it now only adds an additional property for each `accessori` without removing any existing ones - hence you implode them separately in the view.

Answer (score 1):

You can try laravel helper to array

```
collect($acc['accessoriLang'])->implode(',');
```

If you have already array then you can simply use.

```
$collection->implode(',')
```

For more information have a look https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections

```
@foreach ($ProdottoAccessori as $prodotto)
    @if($scheda->id == $prodotto->id)
        @foreach($prodotto['accessori'] as $acc)

                <span>{!! collect($prodotto['accessori'])->implode(',') !!}</span>
        @endforeach
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Hope this helps

Comment: this doesn't do what I need, or maybe I don't know how and where to use it

Comment: @DaFois have a look at updated answer it may solve your problem

Comment: This work but no commas `<span>{!! collect($accNome['accessori'])->implode(',') !!}</span>`

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution. Thanks to @Sebastian Sulinski

In the controller:

```
$ProdottoAccessori = App\Product::has('accessori')->with([
    'productsLang',
      'accessori' => function ($query)  use ($array_prod_id){
          $query->with([
            'accessoriLang'
          ]);
       }
    ])->get();

    $products = $ProdottoAccessori->map(function($product) {
        return $product->accessori->map(function($accessori) {
            $accessori->accessoriLangString = '<span>'.$accessori->accessoriLang->pluck('accessori')->implode(', ').'</span>';
            return $accessori;
        });
    });
```

In the view:

```
@foreach ($ProdottoAccessori as $prodotto)
    @if($scheda->id == $prodotto->id)
        {{ $prodotto->accessori->pluck('accessoriLangString')->implode(', ') }}
    @endif
@endforeach
```

I still don't know why I have to implode 2 times but it works.

This is the output:

```
<span>cerchi in lega</span>, <span>alzacristalli</span>, <span>portapacchi</span>, <span>navigatore</span>
```

Comment: What you've done here won't give you opening and closing `span` for the first and last item.